# why PyMySQL closed so early when using contextmanager and sqlalchemy?

Tags: mysql, sqlalchemy, pymysql, contextmanager

I used python 3's *contextmanager* to manage MySQL connection's close(), 
for simplicity, I wrote a simple example:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from contextlib import contextmanager

@contextmanager
def db_connect():
   DSNs= {'mysql': 'mysql+pymysql://***?charset=utf8'}

   try:
      engine = create_engine(DSNs['mysql'], pool_recycle=1)
   except ImportError:
      raise RuntimeError()

   conn = engine.connect()
   try:
      yield conn
   finally:
      if conn:
        print(threading.currentThread().getName() + " why closed")
        conn.close() 

if __name__ == '__main__':
     with db_connect() as conn:
        for i in range(0, 100):
           sql = """select {0}""".format(i)
           with conn as cur:
              cur.execute(sql)
```

I found I can run query once successfully, when I run the query one more time I got an error "connection closed already"

```
Traceback (most recent call last): ... in _execute_context
conn = self._revalidate_connection()
base.py", line 469, in _revalidate_connection
raise exc.ResourceClosedError("This Connection is closed")
sqlalchemy.exc.ResourceClosedError: This Connection is closed

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
```

Comment: Can you post the code how you use the contextmanager?

Comment: The above code included contextmanager, please check it whether I used it properly, Thks

Comment: I don't think you can use `with conn`. check
 https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement. I think you can try put `with db_connect() as conn:` inside your `for` loop.